# what is the cause of ENODEV error from setsockopt

Tags: sockets

We are using the following code (only a snippet) for setting up several multicast sockets (OS: Redhat Linux):

```
sockfd[i] = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
if (setsockopt(sockfd[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&on, sizeof(on)) < 0) {....}
if (bind (sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr*)&skin, sizeof(skin)) < 0) {....}
if (setsockopt(sockfd[i], IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {....}
```

Everything seems to work for all the sockets except one; the trace shows the following in the failed case:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 6
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9050), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [66560], 4) = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, "\340y\324{\0\0\0\0", 8) = -1 ENODEV (No such device)
```

What could be root the cause for the failure?

Comment: Wrong content of `mreq`? Only you don't show how you set this up.

Comment: That trace shows the last parameter is 8, but [according to this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) `sizeof(mreq)` should be 12 instead (`(sizeof(in_addr) * 2)+sizeof(int)` = `(4*2)+4` = 12). So either `mreq` is not declared as `struct ip_mreqn` (are you using the older `struct ip_mreq` instead?) or your compiler's declaration of `ip_mreqn` is missing the `imr_ifindex` member. Either way, if I'm reading that trace correctly, the `mreq.imr_address` member is being set to `0.0.0.0` which won't work for multicast, you need the actual IP of the interface that is joining the group

Answer (score 0):

The issue was tracked to issue in routing table.  Using "netstat -r" showed that the route to "default" destination was not set.  Once that was set everything started working as expected.  Thanks to all for your help.