Why ENODEV is not documented for setsockopt call?
setsockopt call may fail with ENODEV error, see Error "No such device" in call setsockopt when joining multicast group and what is the cause of ENODEV error from setsockopt for example. However this error code is not listed in any man page for setsockopt I've looked:

https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setsockopt.3p.html
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setsockopt.html

Why is that? Why man pages miss ENODEV error for setsockopt call?

There are error codes specific for different layers and protocols. ENODEV is one of them. See, for example, man 7 packet,

Most likely the socket call failed and you called setsockopt with a bad socket argument.

@stark, at least socket call did not fail in the example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724808/what-is-the-cause-of-enodev-error-from-setsockopt, see strace output.

@dimich, what if I want to create AF_INET socket? man 7 ip still has no ENODEV error code.

@ks1322 So create it. What problem are you trying to solve? setsocktopt() is just an interface to various layers. Man page may describe errors for some error codes but it is not obligated to list all possible error codes. An error may be returned from underlying protocol driver or even a device driver. For example, in case of IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP ENODEV may be returned by IGMP implementation.
